# How test NFC on emulator?

Tags: android, nfc

Android Studio 4.0

I success start android emulator (Android 10.0). Nice.

But I need to pass data between emulators by NFC protocol. Is it possible on emulator to work with NFC?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry for the bad news but ther's no official NFC support in the AVD since Google never implemented it.

Years ago there was an openNFC project but I just found out the website is no longer avaliable.

The only solution looks like is to use USB debugging.